# sharepoint online site collection URL modification

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

We have office 365 tenant with SharePoint subscription.
We also own one domain , say DOMAINNAME.COM 
One of the site collection URL is : `https://domainname.sharepoint.com/sites/appcat`

Now, what we want is, `DOMAINNAME.COM` should open the sharepoint online site collection. How this can be achieved. I have access to tenant administration but we don't have alternate access mapping like in sharepoint on-premise.

Only workaround currently we have is, putting script on domainname.com home page and redirect to sharepoint site collection. But client is not fine with this solution.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 2):

You can only map your own domain to Sharepoint Online public site via SPOnline admin page like [written here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rename-your-SharePoint-Online-Public-Website-address-to-use-your-custom-domain-3d4bd288-772b-4f88-af4d-f025b3825ed3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.).

Unfortunately, this will be only redirection from your DOMAINNAME.COM to SPOnline public site, and end users still will see SPOnline site url in browser.

Comment: this applies only to Public site collections. Ours is Private site collection. Public site collections are discontinued now .

Comment: Yes, for the new accounts it is so. You can try to specify redirection manually in DNS entries of your DOMAINNAME.COM for all requests.

Comment: yeah..that the only option. Client is not happy with those long sharepoint URLs . Anyways, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with private site collections on SharePoint Online currently.
This is because of the SSL requirement (in the E plans) for private site collections. There isn't a way to upload an SSL cert to SharePoint Online so that it can serve requests for that domain and HTTPS.
You can map your vanity domain to your SharePoint Online public web site however (because it doesn't use HTTPS).